# Selecting Random Rows in relation to Random Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

So I've been trying for a few days now and looking all over but I can't seem to find a solution for this situation. Maybe I'm over-thinking it, so I guess this is two questions in one:

1. Am I even going the right direction?
2. Why isn't this working as expected?

**Situation:**

I have a website where users can sign up, creating a "User". After registration, they can then create multiple profiles or "Characters".

I need a way to select a particular number of random users (in this case 12) and then select one of their characters at random.

**Current Data Structure:**

Users Table - {UserID}

Characters Table - {CharacterID, DisplayName, UserID}

**Problem:**

Usually I do this kind of stuff via code, but I wanted to approach this in a purely SQL method primarily because I didn't want to hit the code once for the random list of users and then 12 more times for each random character per user.

Eventually I came to the conclusion that this wasn't something that could be done with a single one-line query (if I'm wrong please correct me, I may just not be seeing the trees in the forest here). So I decided to select the 12 random users, loop through them and on each one select a random character for each user.

This seems to work and from what I can tell, it's not horrendous in terms of performance. However... I'm running into a small problem with the returned data. It only returns 12 rows sometimes. Other times it jumps down to 11 rows or 10 rows and I can't for the life of me figure out why it's doing this. Would anyone be able to shed light on this?

**Code:**

```
Declare @UserTable TABLE(UserID int)
Insert Into @UserTable Select Top 12 UserID From Users Where ((ABS(CAST( (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 10)

Declare @OutputTable TABLE(CharacterID int, CharacterDisplayName nvarchar(MAX), UserID int)

Declare @CurrentUserID int
Select @CurrentUserID = min(UserID) From @UserTable
While @CurrentUserID is not null
Begin
    Insert Into @OutputTable Select Top 1 CharacterID, CharacterDisplayName, UserID FROM CharactersForListing Where UserID = @CurrentUserID Order By NewID()
    Select @CurrentUserID = min(UserID) from @UserTable Where UserID > @CurrentUserID
End

Select * From @OutputTable
```

Comment: How big is your Users table?

Comment: Both tables can be considered small (4000+ Users / 12,000+ Characters). I assume, after reading your answer, that you were going after the Binary Checksum randomizer. I tried playing with that, as well, but as I stated in my comment there, it seemed mess with the row count even more. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? The main query gets 12 random Users. The correlated cross apply gets 1 randomly selected Character for that User.

```
select top 12
    u.UserID
    , c.CharacterID
from Users u
cross apply
(
    select top 1 CharacterID
    from Characters ch
    where ch.UserID = u.UserID
    order by newid()
) c
order by NEWID()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. After seeing this I began testing it and figuring out the best way to use it in the full data scheme. It works beautifully and is much simpler than my original approach! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`Where ((ABS(CAST( (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 10)` is approximately giving you 10% of the table. If you table `Users` is really small, `top 12 *` does not guarantee to give you 12 rows.

If you table is small enough, you can change your `Insert into` query to

```
Insert Into @UserTable Select Top 12 UserID From Users ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @xbb. I actually tried that same thing earlier as a stab in the dark and it ended up making the row counts even more sporadic (7-12). It drove me completely up the wall.